# how to style only child element of specific class whose parent also is of specific class

Tags: css, blogger

Fiddling around with Blogger.

What would be the correct css syntax for styling, say, a `li` element, that has been assigned a specific class, say `selected`, that's located within, say, a `div` element, that's also been assigned a specific class, say `tabs-outer` ?

Comment: Why are we 'saying' this, why aren't you showing the relevant HTML? And when you've tried this yourself, what went wrong, what CSS selector(s) did you attempt to use, where are you stuck?

Comment: @DavidThomas Guess seeking instant guidance at those rare moments when one is nearly getting a headache just at the idea of further research is considered misconduct here on stack exchange. I accept the downvote and apologize.

Comment: No, but asking a question about the appropriate CSS selector for hypothetical HTML is silly, when you could take the thirty seconds and show that HTML. Which is less ambiguous and more clearly understood. Also you're asking a question with no information about what the problem is, besides a lack of understanding, or research, into CSS selectors.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
.tabs-outer li.selected { ... }
```

Note that `li.selected` has no space between the two selectors, making it target any li element that also has the `selected` class.

If you want to get really specific you can do the same with the `div`:

```
div.tabs-outer li.selected { ... }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
.tabs-outer li.selected { ... }
```

Comment: The list element has the class `selected`. It would be just `.tabs-outer li.selected`.

Comment: Ah thanks, I missed that.  Fixed css.